# Assert.True Message Not Showing In NUnit GUI?

Tags: c#, nunit

```
Assert.True(1==1, "blah");
```

When this code runs, "blah" does not appear in the NUnit GUI.  What additional steps need to be taken for me to see "blah" in the "Text Output" tab of NUnit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Assert.True(1==0, "blah");
```

should do the trick.

Comment: What if I want to output text for everything, if it succeeds or fails?  This seems like I'm using NUnit incorrectly if I do this, but I have a reason for why this would be useful.

Comment: Then that's not an assert... that's just a regular print. Asserts are for asserting that a condition is true, not for outputting messages for debugging.

Comment: How do you print to the "Text Output" tab?

Comment: I believe that would be the `Debug.WriteLine` method, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Console.WriteLine it was.  Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5):

The message doesn't appear because the assert is valid.  The `Assert.True` method checks to see if the expression is true and displays the message only if it's `false`.  In this case `1==1` is `true` hence it's not going to show.

Comment: TextOutput is only used to display failure messages?  I'm new to NUnit, so everything is foreign to me here.  Thanks.

Comment: @sooprise, yes the message is only displayed in the case of failure

Comment: Would forcing it to always display a message, Assert.True(false,"Display parameters that were tested whether pass or fail"); be a bad practice? I feel like it would be nice to see all of the parameters used even if they pass.

Comment: @sooprise in my experience no one reads output for succeeded tests. They only care that they pass.  Having a dialog popup for every run would be very annoyngi when you have literally thousands of tests

Comment: I'm planning on having asserts for different database rows, meaning there could be any number of these.  Knowing which ones were tested would be useful, but i agree that in the errors list this is not the right place if they pass.  i now need to figure out how to print neutral text in the Text Output tab. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Console.WriteLine("yourtext")` to display any text in the **TextOutput** tab.

This has the added benefit (as opposed to the other answers) of not to mess with your test results, which is most propably what you want.